# Display markdown table as html table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, r-markdown, pander

I saw this app https://rich.shinyapps.io/regression/ and I wanted to do something similar displaying the regression output as html.

I divided my app in three parts as below.

`server.R` has no "engine" problems and the regression result is correct and pander is converting `summary()` to markdown correctly.

`ui.R` is also working ok but the markdown displayed after `htmlOutput("model")` is suppossed to be obtained from

```
output$model <- renderPrint({
        pander(summary(model()))
      })
```

in `server.R`, and the table is not well displayed even when its a valid markdown table.

**How can I display my markdown summary as a common table like in R Markdown?** my current output is:

[image]

## Full MWE of the app

### global.R

```
#library(shinyapps)
library(googleVis)
library(knitr)
library(pander)
library(shiny)
#library(shinysky)
```

### ui.R

```
# Define UI for application 
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title

  titlePanel("Bivariate Regression"),

  # Sidebar 

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(      
      textInput("name", label = h5("Name"), value = "Name"),
      HTML('</br>'),
      #selectInput("dataset", h5("Choose a dataset:"), choices = c("cars", "longley", "MLB","rock", "pressure")),        
      selectInput("dataset", h5("Choose a dataset:"), choices = c("cars", "longley","rock", "pressure")),        
      HTML('</br>'),
      uiOutput('dv'),    
      HTML('</br>'),
      uiOutput('iv'),
      HTML('</br>')),
      #radioButtons('format', h5('Document format'), c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'), inline = TRUE),
      #downloadButton('downloadReport')),
      #includeHTML('help.html')),

    # main panel 

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                  tabPanel("Data",
                           HTML("</br>Select a data set from the 'Choose a dataset menu' or enter your own data below </br> </br>"),
                           numericInput("obs", label = h5("Number of observations to view"), 10),
                           tableOutput("view")),

                  tabPanel("Summary Statistics",
                           verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
                           textInput("text_summary", label = "Interpretation", value = "Enter text...")),

                  tabPanel("Model",                   
                           htmlOutput("model"),
                           textInput("text_model", label = "Interpretation", value = "Enter text..."))
      )                         
    ))
))
```

### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # list of data sets
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "cars" = mtcars,
           "longley" = longley,
           "MLB" = mlb11,    
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure, 
           "Your Data" = df())
  })

  # dependent variable
  output$dv = renderUI({
    selectInput('dv', h5('Dependent Variable'), choices = names(datasetInput()))
  })

  # independent variable
  output$iv = renderUI({
    selectInput('iv', h5('Independent Variable'), choices = names(datasetInput()))
  })

  # regression formula
  regFormula <- reactive({
    as.formula(paste(input$dv, '~', input$iv))
  })

  # bivariate model
  model <- reactive({
    lm(regFormula(), data = datasetInput())
  })


  # create graphics 

  # data view 
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)
  })

  # summary statistics
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(cbind(datasetInput()[input$dv], datasetInput()[input$iv]))
  })

  # bivariate model
  output$model <- renderPrint({
    pander(summary(model()))
  })

  # residuals
  output$residuals_hist <- renderPlot({
    hist(model()$residuals, main = paste(input$dv, '~', input$iv), xlab = 'Residuals') 
  })

  output$residuals_scatter <- renderPlot({
    plot(model()$residuals ~ datasetInput()[,input$iv], xlab = input$iv, ylab = 'Residuals')
    abline(h = 0, lty = 3) 
  })

  output$residuals_qqline <- renderPlot({
    qqnorm(model()$residuals)
    qqline(model()$residuals) 
  })

})
```

Comment: If you want to convert the markdown table into HTML, you can use `pandoc`, eg wrapped in `rmarkdown::render`

Comment: like `rmarkdown::render(pander( the_regression() ))`? that's doesn't work :S

Comment: check out `markdown::markdownToHTML`